# rails searchlogic and will_paginate undefined method `order' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0x37530ac>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, searchlogic

Does anyone have the same problem or a working solution?
I get always this error message, here are model, controller and view code

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_reader :per_page
    @@per_page = 10
end

def index
   @search = Profile.search(params[:search])
    @profiles = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

<%= will_paginate order @profiles , :by => :created_at, :as => "name" %>
```

please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the first parameter that should be passed to the `will_paginate` view helper method is the collection you want to paginate:

```
<%= will_paginate @profiles %>
```

—whereas searchlogic's `order` helper method returns a link, not a collection. You probably want to do this:

```
<%= order @profiles, :by => :created_at, :as => 'name' %>
<%= will_paginate @profiles %>
```

I'm not sure if it will work as intended, I haven't tried it.

Comment: oh, thanks for the quick answer.
I want to use the order method from searchlogic in the view.
How can I do that in combination with will_paginate ?

Comment: Hey, I got it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
<%= will_paginate  @profiles  %>
<%= order @search, :by => :created_at %>

Upps, didn't press the refresh button. 
Thankyou, thankyou, thankyou

Comment: can this be moved into the controller?